# tanf() function returns wrong value in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got a problem, but can't find the error. I'm trying to calculate the tangent of an angle. I tried both in radians and in degree, i got wrong answer. My code:

```
CGFloat tiltAngleDegrees = tiltAngle * 180.0f / M_PI - 90.0f; // in degrees
NSLog(@"Tan Angle: %f", tanf(tiltAngleDegrees));
```

I tried for Angle:-6.027872

I got answer: 0.261010

Answer that i calculated on calculator: -0.105596

I thought it was going to be a simple task, but i hit a wall - can't find what's going wrong. I hope some of you can point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: @maddy i tried in radians too, get wrong result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tanf` requires radians.

Simply do:

```
float tangent = tanf(-6.027872);
```

The result will be 0.261009.

This is the correct result.

A result of -0.105596 for -6.027872 means that you entered -6.027872 as degrees in your calculator. Put your calculator in radians mode and then you will see the correct result of 0.261009 just as you do with this `tanf` function.

Comment: float tangent = tanf(-6.027872);
    NSLog(@"tangent: %f", tangent);

Comment: got this, tangent: 0.261009

Answer (score 1):

as @rmaddy said `tanf` requires radians

In your case I suppose your angle is in radians

```
tiltAngle = -6.027872 //in radians
```

so

```
float tangent = tanf(-6.027872);
```

gives you 0.26101 which is the correct answer.

In your code sample you convert `tiltAngle` from radians to degrees but also **substract 90°**. Is there any reason for that ? At that moment the correct result will be -3.8313.

However the problem is that you set your calculator in degrees. If -6.027872 is in degrees at that moment you will get -0.105596 which is wrong.

Comment: then 0.26101 radian = -0.105596 degrees??

Comment: this function give me in radians and calculator give me in degree.... both will be equal i.e 0.26101 radian = -0.105596 degrees???